# ENVI 5.6.2 HSV problem

Tags: raster, envi, digital-image-processing, resampling

I've used ENVI a lot in the past, but am a bit rusty. I have never ran into this problem and can't find anything online about it. I'm trying to do HSV sharpening with 3 band multispectral data and a panchromatic image. All of my images are Landsat 9, .TIFF format from earth explorer.

When I run the tool the input bands window appears, I input my 3 bands in the first window, click okay and I get, "the input bands must be in byte data." I have no idea what this means. I've saved the file as a native .ENVI file, that doesn't work, and I can't find anything on how to convert the raster into "byte data", or what "byte data" actually means. I have tried using a raster that I made using the build band stack tool, I've tried using the files directly from earth explorer, converting them to .ENVI files, however I end up with the same error. I've watched walk through videos on how to do the sharpening and none of the video people mention anything about the "byte data".

I have used the spectral resample tool, when I do that the result is just a black image. I tell ENVI to use "predefined filter function" and select Landsat 8 OLI. The HSV sharpening tool will accept that raster, however when I preform the sharpening the output is the same as the panchromatic image, which makes sense as the other image is just a black raster (i just wanted to see if it works). Please anyone I need a simple way to solve the problem, I bet it is an easy fix I just cant figure it out.